# Code for image manipulation produces no result/output

Tags: python-3.x, class, python-imaging-library

I am working on a project that where I am required to use classes and objects to manipulate an image in Python using PIL.

I have eliminated formatted the path to the file correctly so there must be something in the code itself.

```
class image_play(object):
    def __init__(self,im_name):
        self.im_name = im_name


    def rgb_to_gray_image(self):
        im = Image.open(self.im_name)
        im = im.convert('LA')
        return im

    # editing pixels of image to white
    def loop_over_image(self):
        im = Image.open(self.im_name)
        width, height = im.size
        # nested loop over all pixels of image
        temp = []
        for i in range(width):
          for j in range(height):
            temp.append((255,255,255)) # append tuple for the RGB values for each pixel

        image_out = Image.new(im.mode,im.size)  #create new image using PIl
        image_out.putdata(temp) #use the temp list to create the image
        return image_out

pic = image_play('test.png')

picGray = pic.rgb_to_gray_image()

picWhite = pic.loop_over_image()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added picGray.show() and picWhite.show() an now I have view-able output. Hmmmm...